# unit, integration, system tests for Codeblocks IDE

Tags: testing, ide, automated-tests, system-testing

I recently was given control of a project that is based on the Codeblocks IDE.  This project consists of large make scripts, gcc for motorola microcontrollers, and example C programs.  The code is under subversion source-control, but there are no test scripts.

I am wondering what the best test package for windows based software is.  I would like the ability to launch the software, open a project and compile.  Then I would look in the output directory for specific files, binaries, etc.  I have the ability to provision a dedicated VM to this task.

I'm wondering if there's a better way for testing than fully launching the IDE and clicking through menus.

I wish this project was assembled with Test-driven development in mind, but now I'm being forced to add in test afterwards.

Thanks for any advice u might have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking into tools such as eggPlant.  Unfortunatly this tool costs $6000. I cannot afford this right now so I am still not sure of the answer.  Thanks for your input tho.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you need Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 bundle.
Microsoft Test Manager 2010 for test case/test script/defect tracing management system, even more, you could use it as testing environment management system, including virtual machine(Hyper-V).

And you could also use the Visual Studio as the team project management tool, it has some build-in template for different agile project type.

You could get more information from MSDN.

You should get a try at this bundle,